# Laravel how to Order by relation in scope?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, scope

I have the following scope in User model

```
$query->with('country')
          ->when($filters['search'] ?? null, function ($query, $search) {
              return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhereHas('country', function ($query) use ($search) {
                        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
                    });
          });

       
            $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
       }

        return $query;
    }
```

I am pretty new to Laravel - I currently the above query is sorting by user name but I would like to sort by country name. I can do this with **country_id** as there is a relation but not sure how to sort by country name.

Thanks

Comment: Just try with `$query->orderBy('country.name', 'asc');`

Comment: `function ($query, $search)` should be `function ($query) use ($search)`. Sorting by a relationship column  in the query is not possible. You can do that in the resulting collection however with `sortBy(callback(value, key))`. Using a join would allow you to do this kind of sorting though

Answer (score 1):

there are two approaches we can use to order these users by their company. The first is using a join:

```
$users = User::select('users.*')
->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')
->orderBy('companies.name')
->get();
```

Here is the generated SQL for this query:

```
select users.*
from users
inner join countries on countries.id = users.country_id
order by countries.name asc
```

The second way is using a subquery:

```
$users = User::orderBy(Country::select('name')
    ->whereColumn('countries.id', 'users.country_id')
)->get();
```

And you can see the reference here: [ordering database queries by relationship columns in laravel](https://reinink.ca/articles/ordering-database-queries-by-relationship-columns-in-laravel)